# ASP.NET MVC - Ajax.ActionLink with a HtmlString

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to use an Ajax.ActionLink method with an HtmlString as the link text and not a string?

The reason for this is that I want to do something like so:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("<span style='highlight'>Hello</span> World", ...)
```

If I try this now, it'll return the span etc.. on my page. So I need to return it as a HtmlString

EDIT:

Just tried:

```
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
        this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
        IHtmlString linkText,
        string actionName,
        Object routeValues,
        AjaxOptions ajaxOptions
    )
    {
        return ActionLink(ajaxHelper, linkText, actionName, routeValues, ajaxOptions);
    }
```

And I got a stack overflow exception?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. you will have to do some extra work to extract only required text for action link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by using the solution found here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1702210/4518688.aspx/1?Re+Quick+question+about+Ajax+ActionLink+and+span

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe so.  ASP.NET MVC will HTML encode the text so that it appears as such.  What you need to use is an overload of the `AjaxExtensions.ActionLink()` method.  Something like this would work:

[AjaxExtenions.ActionLink()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470546.aspx)

The method parameter list:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Notice how there is an `Object` form HTML attributes.  *But*, that would just be for the HTML attributes of that anchor element.  If you are **really** set on using a `<span />` element, then your best bet would be to write a custom `HtmlHelper` for that.

### Example

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "This is your link text",
    "SomeActionName",
    null, // or you could pass route values if you like
    new AjaxOptions() { }, // whatever Ajax options you want
    null); // not passing any html attributers
```

Comment: Couldn't I just set the linkText to an IHtmlString data type and return my new ActionLink?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff I don't think so.  I believe inside the `ActionLink()` method the string is HTML encoded.  Therefore, no matter what string you pass to it you will have the same end-result.

Comment: I just tried it and it returned a stack overflow exception, seems its referencing itself...

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff You can't pass an `AjaxHelper` object to it.  That's just the way extension methods are made.  See my example in my edited post.