# create ajax actionlink with html elements in the link text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-ajax

I would like to convert a link to an ajax action link.  I can't figure out how to display html elements within the link text?

Here is the original link:

```
<a href="#onpageanchor" id="myId" class="myClass" title="My Title."><i class="icon"></i>Click Me</a>
```

Here is the ajax actionlink:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("<i class='icon'></i>Click Me", "MyActionMethod", new { id = "testId" },
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            UpdateTargetId = "mytargetid"
                        }, new
                        {
                            id = "myId",
                            @class = "myClass",
                            title="My Title."
                        })
```

the link text rendered is the actual string: `"<i class='icon'></i>Click Me</a>"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194876/asp-net-mvc-ajax-actionlink-with-a-htmlstring

Comment: Have you thought about just using jQuery to send the request?

Comment: Please, see my answer to this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341649/asp-net-mvc-ajax-actionlink-with-image/17151675#17151675

Comment: @FiveTools any chance you could mark my answer as correct if it did indeed help you out?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

over a year late and everything but this is what I use. Hope it helps someone else.

```
@Ajax.RawActionLink(string.Format("<i class='icon'></i>Click Me"), "ActionResultName", null, new { item.Variable}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "taget-div", LoadingElementId = "target-div" }, new { @class = "class" })
```

Then the helper...

```
    public static MvcHtmlString RawActionLink(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var repID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var lnk = ajaxHelper.ActionLink(repID, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, ajaxOptions, htmlAttributes);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(lnk.ToString().Replace(repID, linkText));
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for; fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

I have created Ajax.ActionLink to display image instead of link text

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink(".", "Delete_Share_Permission", "Share", new { delwhich = "one", delid = @UserSharingDetails.PK_User_Sharing_Id }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "sharelist", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "return confirmdeleteone();" }, new { @class = "deleteButton", @id = "fna" })
```

Applying class

```
 .deleteButton {        
    background-image: url("/images/DeleteData.png");
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 13px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    display: block;
    top: 5px;
}
```

I hope this code is useful to you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" Name", "AjaxGetAllUsers", "Admin", new { sortBy = ViewBag.SortByName, search = Request.QueryString["search"] }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "userlist", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }, new { @class = "fa fa-sort" })
```